# Why I can't dowload PDF or PNG file ??, HightChart

Tags: highcharts

Why I can't download PDF or PNG file ??
I'm doing drilldown-chart
When I Show data-table: `load:  Highcharts.drawTable` I can download PDF and PNG file
But when I change

```
load() {
                    if (this.renderer.forExport) {
                        Highcharts.drawTable(this);
                    }
                }
```

I can't download PDF and PNG file.

[This is link my code on Google Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f4OjHccolygums7AfKY1u3kBdWxb9QzIt_GHmVvRCQc/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code and found the following errors:

- You should change this part of the code if you don't use the xAxis category type:

  ```
  chart.xAxis[0].categories.forEach(function(name, i) {
  renderer.text(
      name,
      cellLeft + cellPadding,
      tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
    )
    .css({
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    })
    .add();
  });
  ```
- valueSuffix = ' °C' was commented

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lxtekgd9/

Comment: if using this method . it's can't hide data-table or using method                                      
                  load() {
                    if (this.renderer.forExport) {
                        Highcharts.drawTable(this);
                    }
                }

Comment: I don't understand - could you reproduce your issue on the online editor?

Comment: I didn't understand this method for show data-table when export (this.renderer.forExport)

Comment: I don't know what you are writing about - I haven't use this condition in the above demo